# Kubuntu 16.10 - wifi stuck on 'waiting for authorization'

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu

It used to work but I guess one of the updates broke it.  I can connect to the wifi on my phone and other OS's. Unsure of what would cause this.  I have tried deleting the profile for each connection and re-entering passwords but nothing.  IF I remove passwords for the connections it will work.

Comment: Recently I had a similar problem. I had disabled WMM on the router and this caused the problem. There was some info about it in `dmesg`. Try to sign into the network and then check `dmesg` for any new info. If you don't find any useful info, please post the info described here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos thanks!

Comment: I have WMM enabled.  I have this error "ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready"  when I run dmesg

Comment: Okay, just follow the instructions outlined in the following link to provided the information needed to diagnose the issue please: http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/167115 thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try this if you have network-manager enabled :

```
sudo nmcli dev wifi
```

to find your `wifi ssid` and

```
sudo nmcli dev wifi connect <your ssid> password <your pass>
```

Looks like network-manager is waiting for root permission.

Comment: It worked! Thanks, although the only bad thing is that, in your bash history the wifi password, will remain visible.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want your password to appear in your history just leave out the password part and add the 
`-a` option and it will ask for it after you hit enter:

```
 sudo nmcli -a dev wifi connect <your ssid>
```

From `man nmcli`

```
 -a | --ask    When using this option nmcli will stop and ask for any missing 
  required arguments, so do not use this option for non-interactive purposes like
scripts. This option controls, for example, whether you will be prompted for a 
password if it is required for connecting to a network.
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was something with the KDE Wallet system. I've installed some updates, and those seem to wipe my old wallet and make it corrupted - ie the wallet could not been opened.

The fix was to create a new wallet and set it as default.

Comment: Exactly my issue but I'm not in Ubuntu, I'm using OpenSUSE

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me and I hadn't done anything. Turned out there was something wrong with the "Bbox" from Bouygues ISP. After 2 hours on the phone they sorted it out.