# Kubuntu Network Manager does not connect to Wifi/VPN any more (Waiting for authorization)

Tags: networking, kubuntu, network-manager, kde

I have some problems connecting to Wifi networks using network manager using Kubuntu 18 with KDE/Plasma. There were no problems a fews day ago, but now it gets stuck on "Waiting for authorization" (Wifi) or "Needs authorization" when trying to connect to a VPN.

Tested with several different Wifis. I managed to create a working connection using nmcli command (but only with WPA personal encryption. Doesn't work with WPA enterprise encryption methods) (see [Kubuntu 16.10 - wifi stuck on 'waiting for authorization'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/869955/kubuntu-16-10-wifi-stuck-on-waiting-for-authorization)).

Any ideas?

Comment: Running into same problem.  A dialog would show up allowing me to type in a password, but now there doesn't appear to be one. I was thinking it might be some wallet issue?  But I'm not having any luck.  The dialog doesn't show up and eventually I get an error saying: "Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken."  (So, reply timeout for me...).